# Packing customers into buckets

Tags: r, statistics, k-means, bin-packing

I have say 25 customers. Each customer has a number of users of our system, e.g. customer 1 has 45 users, customer 2 has 46 users... customer 25 has 1000 users.

I want to bin each customer into a bucket, where each bucket contains a roughly equal number of users. I know that I want 5 buckets in total.

(The buckets here represent servers, I want to apportion my clients to different servers where the total number of users per server is roughly equal, so as to prevent overloading the servers. 1 client has to be on the same server (i.e. can't split 1 client over 2 servers).

Any idea of suitable methods for apportioning customers to buckets? I thought some clustering methods might work (I tried kmeans using R), but I cant seem to find ways of stipulating that the total number of users in each cluster is roughly the same.

Here's my R code as an example of what I've done so far:

```
#Create dataset
r <- data.frame(users=c(1000, 960, 920, 870, 850, 700, 600, 550, 520, 500, 420, 400, 390, 300, 210, 200, 160, 80, 70, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45))
#Try kmeans clustering
fit <- kmeans(r, 5) 
#get cluster means
aggregate(r, by=list(fit$cluster),FUN = mean)
#append cluster assignment
r <- data.frame(r,fit$cluster)

#Plot cluster
library(cluster)
clusplot(r, fit$cluster, color=TRUE, shade=TRUE, labels=2, lines=0)
library(fpc)
plotcluster(r, fit$cluster)
```

This clusters my customers into buckets, but the number of users in each bucket is not roughly equal.

I've tagged this as an R problem, but if there's a simple solution in some other package I'm all ears :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the recommended solution for such 'constant sum sampling ' is.  Here's my shot at it -- sort the items, convert to matrix where each column represents a sample, reverse every other row.

Here's the code:

```r
set.seed(1024)
r <- data.frame(users=c(1000, 960, 920, 870, 850, 700, 600, 550, 520, 500, 420, 400, 390, 300, 210, 200, 160, 80, 70, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45))

a<-   r$users #runif(n = 25, 100,400) #rnorm(25,100,100) # 1:25
#hist(a)
df<- data.frame(id=1:25,x=a)

# sort 
x<- df$id[order(df$x)]
# convert to matrix
#each column of this matrix represetns one sample
xm<-matrix(x,ncol=5,byrow = T); xm
oldsum<-apply(matrix(df$x,ncol=5,byrow = T), 2,sum)

#flip alternate rows of this sorted matrix
i= 1:nrow(xm)
im=i[c(F,T)]
xm[im,]
xm[im,]<- rev(xm[im,])

# new matrix of indeices 
xm

#hence the new matrix of values
xm2<- matrix(a[c(xm)],ncol = 5, byrow = F)
xm
xm2

newsum<- (apply(xm2, 2,sum))

# improvement
rbind(oldsum,newsum)
barplot(rbind(oldsum,newsum)[1,])
barplot(rbind(oldsum,newsum)[2,])

# each column of following matrix represents one sample 
#(values are indices in original vector a)
xm
```

Comment: I think this does the job! I tip my hat to you. Thanks so much for the effort :-)

Comment: Nice to know it helped. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying clustering (which solves a very diffefent problem, namely putting *similar* values into clusters) you have a classic variant of the [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) here.

These tend to be NP-hard, so finding the optimal solution is very expensive. Instead, try a greedy strategy: Estimate the minimum bucket size as total/buckets. Process elements in descending size, and always put them into the bucket with the most space available. For better results, add an optimization function that trades elements between pairs of buckets if this improves the result. If you have many small values, such a strategy may work very well.

Comment: Yep this looks like a bin packing problem alright! Thanks for the response. The response by @R.S below looks like it will work! Delighted :-)